# How to select menu from SAP GUI menu bar

Tags: sap-gui

I'm trying to get to work the first line in the code. It is recorded with SAP GUI recording. I tried to check what it shows as text when chopping the code in pieces. The last line shows the correct option "Close" but it does not work in the code. How others have succeeded to choose sub options from menu bar? The correct path is Functions->Restrict processing->Close.

```vba
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]/menu[8]/menu[6]").select     'does not work

MsgBox CStr(session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar").Children.Count)        'shows 8
MsgBox session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]").text                'shows function
MsgBox Cstr(session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]").Children.Count)'shows 0?
MsgBox session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]/menu[8]").text        'does not work
MsgBox session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]/menu[8]/menu[6]").text'shows close
```

Comment: What is the exact symptom of "does not work in the code"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry of course I should have attach an error message but it says "The control could not be found by id" on that row which I stated "does not work" eventhough it was recorded with sap gui script recording and it gave that line and it works when you choose manually in CO02 transaction: Functions->Restrict processing->Close. So I want to close several production orders with a script.